# Subset Matrix using a vector

Tags: r, subset

So, I think this is probably a basic question but here it goes. Imagine I have the following matrix:

```
> str(MatrixA)
num [1:20, 1:127] 1 3 2 1 1 2 2 4 1 2 ...
```

Basically a matrix with 20 rows and 127 columns and each entry is an positive integer. I also have the following vector:

```
> n
[1] 5 5 5 5
```

What I want to do is to subset the matrix by using this vector. Meaning, I want to use the vector to get the first five rows from the matrix and then the next five rows, and so on. I tried to use the subset function but I couldn't make it work (it gives me an error saying that the subset must be logical).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if you don't mind coercing to a data frame `split(as.data.frame(MatrixA), rep.int(seq_along(n), n))`

Comment: @ rarw, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(2 * 5), nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
n <- c(2, 1, 2)
Map(function(i, j) M[(i - j + 1):i, , drop = FALSE], cumsum(n), n)
# [[1]]
#            [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] -0.2080075 -0.0146956
# [2,] -1.5513436  0.2253790
#
# [[2]]
#        [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] 0.8447 -0.4891574
#
# [[3]]
#           [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] 0.4916745  1.4980913
# [2,] 0.4789787 -0.3118559
```

Comment: Thank, that was helpful but it makes the next steps more difficult. Cheers

Comment: Perhaps, if `n` is short (but then why not to do all this manually?). Otherwise using `assign` and multiple objects instead of a list is typically a bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you regarding the use of assign and multiple objects, but this method produces: > str(test)
 num [1:635, 1:4] 1 3 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ... i.e. it coerces the values of all five rows into a single column

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean, then see the update; `Map` doesn't simplify the result.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That solves the issue and it has the advantage of not creating multiple objects. I have marked your answer as the correct one based on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a general response, imagine you have a matrix with `nrow` rows, and you want to make subsets by each `k` rows. Then, you can use the following code:

```
# A sequence until `nrow` every `k` units
  s <- seq(0, nrow, by = k)
# Every, . . . (5 rows)
  k <- 5
# Build M1, . . ., Mk sub-matrices
  for (i in 1:ceiling(nrow/k)){
     assign(paste("M",i,sep ="") ,M[(s[i] + 1): s[i+1],])

  }
```

So, now you just need to call `M1`,  . . .  `M4` for your example in order to get the sub-matrices

Comment: Yes, that works for I what I want to accomplish! Thank you